# How to get a vale of price in a certain condition, Pine Script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

im new in pine script, im trying to get price(close) every time a this condition happend

when `rsi > rsi[1]` and after `rsi < rsi[1]` a condition its meet, theres a way to get price(close) every time this condition happend?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ta.valuewhen()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_ta%7Bdot%7Dvaluewhen) function for that.

> Returns the value of the `source` series on the bar where the
> `condition` was true on the nth most recent occurrence.

```
close_cond_price = ta.valuewhen(your_condition, close, 0)
```